# should we add -moz- or other vendor prefix to animate.css?

Tags: css, animation

in animate.css by http://daneden.github.io/animate.css it doesnt use other vendor prefix except -webkit- should we add ourself?
why it doesnt used other prefixes?

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        .animated {
              -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
              -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
               animation-duration: 1s;
              -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
             -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
              animation-fill-mode: both;
            }

            .animated.infinite {
              -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
              animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            }
```

Comment: Hi there,

Webkit-code is for the chrome and works in opera also...this code is working in mozilla latest version but it will not be supported in the some old mozilla versions for that you can do some changes in your css and that would be like this.

Comment: just copy past the css property in which you find webkit and try removing webkit and adding moz in place of there. thats it.

Comment: why it doesn't have by default?

Comment: @peyman unless you're targeting Safari < 3 or FF < 5 no, you don't have to add the prefix to be compatible with all latest versions of browsers. Why it's like this I'm not sure as the code was updated only 14 days ago, so it's definitely not because it's out of date ...